# MySQL to SQL Server - Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'mictest'

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, migration

First, I tried to migrate my databases with SQL Server Migration Assistant for MySql and it worked fine.

But now, I have some problems with my code.

I had this line on MYSQL version :

```
$fct="SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `USER` LIKE CONVERT( _utf8 '$LOGIN' USING latin1 ) COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci AND `PASS` LIKE CONVERT( _utf8 '$PASS'USING latin1 ) COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci";
```

This line worked fine but when i try to put this on my SQL Version i get :

Error : `SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax with the keyword 'mictest'.` (which is my $LOGIN)

I though it was a problem with "quotes" so I also tried this but it is not working :

```
$fct="SELECT * FROM users WHERE USER LIKE CONVERT( _utf8 '$LOGIN' USING latin1 ) COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci AND PASS LIKE CONVERT( _utf8 '$PASS' USING latin1 ) COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci";
```

Comment: `CONVERT( _utf8'$LOGIN' USING latin1 )` not `CONVERT( _utf8 '$LOGIN' USING latin1 )`

Comment: If you check the [TSQL CONVERT function documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx), you'd know why...  You need to change the query to use the [COLLATE function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184391.aspx).

Comment: I tried to find more information about how to use COLLLATE in a different way but didn't succes for the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you did a migration from MYSQL DB, just check that ... `USING latin1 ) COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci` ... is always usefull and correct.

Some mistakes can come from that. I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the space after `_utf8`:

```
CONVERT( _utf8'$LOGIN' USING latin1 )
              ^---no space
```

Comment: See my comment to the question

Comment: Not working in my code with :  `$fct="SELECT * FROM users WHERE USER LIKE CONVERT( _utf8'$LOGIN' USING latin1 ) COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci AND PASS LIKE CONVERT( _utf8'$PASS' USING latin1 ) COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci"`;

I tried to find more information about how to use COLLLATE in a different way but didn't succes for the moment.